# How do I allow fans/friends to tag photo to a business site on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, photos, facebook-tags

My company's Facebook page settings are all set to public, yet my friends and fans cannot tag a photo with my business. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The steps may be a little different now. Be on your page and then
Edit Settings>Tagging Ability  and check the box to allow others to tag photos posted
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The option to do this is separate from setting a page as public. To enable photo tagging on your page, click `Edit Page` while at your Facebook page. Then, click `Manage Permissions`. Finally, check the box labeled `People can tag photos posted by [Page Name]`